# Excel VSTO C# change Marker fill color of Chart series always apply only 1 color to multiple series

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am trying to change Marker Fore Color of series 4 and 6 to two different colors, but somehow they have the same color.
Please kindly advice

```
series1.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = (int)(0x000000);
        series2.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = (int)(0xFF0000);
        series3.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = (int)(0xA9D18E);

        series4.Select();
        series4.Format.Line.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
        series4.MarkerStyle = XlMarkerStyle.xlMarkerStyleAutomatic;
        series4.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = (int)(0x0000FF);
        series4.Format.Fill.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
        series4.Format.Fill.Solid();
       

        series5.Select();
        series5.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = (int)(0x9609ED);

        series6.Select();
        series6.Format.Line.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
        series6.MarkerStyle = XlMarkerStyle.xlMarkerStyleAutomatic;
       
        series6.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = (int)(0xED7D31);
        series6.Format.Fill.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
        series6.Format.Fill.Solid();
```

I also generate VBA macro from Excel (for comparing), the macro will only turns 2 series from Lines to no-line and change Marker color only. This macro works.

```
Sub Macro1()

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(5).Select
Selection.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
Selection.MarkerStyle = -4105
With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent2
    .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.25
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Select
Selection.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
Selection.MarkerStyle = -4105
Selection.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
Selection.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent5
    .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.25
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With
End Sub
```

Updated Solution: I found solution, even not sure why it is: just change order of the statement as below

```
series6.Select();
series6.Format.Line.Visible = 
Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
series6.MarkerStyle = XlMarkerStyle.xlMarkerStyleAutomatic;
series6.Format.Fill.Visible = 
Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
series6.Format.Fill.Solid();
series6.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = (int)(0xED7D31);
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a VBA macro recorder available in Excel so you could find out the required sequence of properties and methods for that?

Comment: Yes thanks Eugene Astafiev, I did that, so that I know what I need to change for each series, before I ask the question. The order of statements for each series originally was the same with recorded macro, but still the same issue. The order of statements in the question is something I tried last, but still no luck.

Comment: So, the generated VBA macro works correctly? Can you post it as well to compare with your existing code?

Comment: I edited the question, added generated VBA Macro to change 2 Series to dotted marker , no line, with different colors. My C# code is similar but does not work

Comment: Added solution in Question